# How to set textView in custom row view of listView

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to set textView in custom row view of listView like below but the app crashes returning null pointer exception

```
TextView txtrow = (TextView) getListView().getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.text11);
txtrow.setText("text");
```

but when i put it under setOnClickListener it works

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView txtrow = (TextView) getListView().getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.text11);
            txtrow.setText("text");
        }
    });
```

Comment: getChildAt(i), i is the item's position of listView.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this inside your ListView's adapter. Whatever data you are using the back your adapter should contain the text you want so that you can set it on the appropriate TextView when you actually create the row view in `getView()`.

It's important to note that `getChildAt(index)` returns the child at the given index *from the ListView's current children*. In other words, `getChildAt(0)` does *not* necessarily give you the list item at position 0. The user may have scrolled the list so that it now shows data from positions 10 through 15 (for example), in which case `getChildAt(0)` gives you the view for position 10, not position 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
To set text in custom row in listview 
Please follow the following points 
1. custom arrayadapter by extending Arrayadpater (for simple)
2. and overwrite getview as following

 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    return rowView;
  }

3. and set the adapter to the listview 
And for more detial please refer this site
[http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html][1]
```